# Column not found: 1054 Champ 'payment_gateway' inconnu dans field list using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I followed an ecommerce training using laravel, and I want to make online payment by paypal cart, but it gives me error in the field `payment_gateway` of table orders, `Column not found: 1054 Field 'payment_gateway' unknown in field list`.

Hello, I followed an ecommerce training using laravel, and I want to make online payment by paypal cart, but it gives me error in the field `payment_gateway` of table orders, `Column not found: 1054 Field 'payment_gateway' unknown in field list`.

**checkoutController.php**

```
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function paypalCheckout(Request $request)
    {
        // Check race condition when there are less items available to purchase
        if ($this->productsAreNoLongerAvailable()) {
            return back()->withErrors('Sorry! One of the items in your cart is no longer avialble.');
        }
        $gateway = new \Braintree\Gateway([
            'environment' => config('services.braintree.environment'),
            'merchantId' => config('services.braintree.merchantId'),
            'publicKey' => config('services.braintree.publicKey'),
            'privateKey' => config('services.braintree.privateKey')
        ]);
        $nonce = $request->payment_method_nonce;
        $result = $gateway->transaction()->sale([
            'amount' => round(getNumbers()->get('newTotal') / 100, 2),
            'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
            'options' => [
                'submitForSettlement' => true
            ]
        ]);
        $transaction = $result->transaction;
        if ($result->success) {
            $order = $this->addToOrdersTablesPaypal(
                $transaction->paypal['payerEmail'],
                $transaction->paypal['payerFirstName'].' '.$transaction->paypal['payerLastName'],
                null
            );
            Mail::send(new OrderPlaced($order));
            // decrease the quantities of all the products in the cart
            $this->decreaseQuantities();
            Cart::instance('default')->destroy();
            session()->forget('coupon');

            return redirect()->route('confirmation.index')->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
        } else {
            $order = $this->addToOrdersTablesPaypal(
                $transaction->paypal['payerEmail'],
                $transaction->paypal['payerFirstName'].' '.$transaction->paypal['payerLastName'],
                $result->message
            ); 
            return back()->withErrors('An error occurred with the message: '.$result->message);
        }
    }
```

**function addToOrdersTablesPaypal**

```
protected function addToOrdersTablesPaypal($email, $name, $error)
    {
        // Insert into orders table
        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
            'billing_email' => $email,
            'billing_name' => $name,
            'billing_discount' => getNumbers()->get('discount'),
            'billing_discount_code' => getNumbers()->get('code'),
            'billing_subtotal' => getNumbers()->get('newSubtotal'),
            'billing_tax' => getNumbers()->get('newTax'),
            'billing_total' => getNumbers()->get('newTotal'),
            'error' => $error,
            'payment_gateway' => 'paypal',
        ]);

        // Insert into order_product table
        foreach (Cart::content() as $item) {
            OrderProduct::create([
                'order_id' => $order->id,
                'product_id' => $item->model->id,
                'quantity' => $item->qty,
            ]);
        }

        return $order;
    }
```

**orders table**
[image]

**error**
[image]

Comment: Error is self-explanatory. The `orders` table doesn't have a `payment_gateway` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be a typo when typing `payement_gateway => payment_gateway`

Answer (score 0):

make sure of:

1- add payment_gateway to Order model's fillable array

2-the column payment_gateway is in table 'orders' columns...